# Match line breaks inside of quotes

Tags: regex, parsing, vim

I need to delete every single line break that's inside of quotes, (replace \n with a space) in a way that this:

```
 <tag>
     abc: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
     abcd: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"

     abcde: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
     TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
     TEXT"

     abcdef:TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
   </tag>
```

Becomes this:

```
<tag>
     abc: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
     abcd: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"

     abcde: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXT"

     abcdef:TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
   </tag>
```

Note that I'm ok with a field with multiple lines, what I don't want is any line break.

I am able to replace all line breaks in the file:

%s/\n/    /

And I am able to replace all the quotes and its contents in the file:

%s/".*"/    /

But I can't match the \n inside of the quotes.

%s/".*\n"/    /

How can I get this done?
Thanks!!

Comment: Provide all details in question, not in image links.

Comment: In this case the images are secondary; they're exactly what I said in question, just easier to see :)

Comment: Maybe try `:S!/     field    1:"/d`...

Comment: @anubhava sorry, I corrected it in the question.

Comment: @l'L'l didn't work

Comment: You are right indeed. In my personal case, I need to compile the content of the same field, in various tags, which is a bit different than what I posted here. so I messed it up a little bit. I now corrected it for the last time, I am sorry

Comment: add an example, before and after. I don't know what do you want by reading your question.

Comment: After struggling a little bit more (and as @sidyll mentioned), I realized it would be easier to do with a replace.
Summarizing, what I want is to delete every line break inside of quotes. So I completly edited the question. Tks again.

Comment: Does it have to be `vim`? Shell tools like awk, sed would be much better.

Comment: Absolutely, anything will do just fine (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` may work for you with a loop:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e $'/^[^"]*"[^"]+$/{N;s/[[:blank:]]*\\n[[:blank:]]*/ /;}' -e 'ta' file
```

```
 <tag>
     abc: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
     abcd: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"

     abcde: "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXT"

     abcdef:TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT"
</tag>
```

Comment: I got to a solution with awk moments before your answer, which also worked, thank you!! I'm leaving it here to whom it may assist.

awk '(NR-1)%2{$1=$1}1' RS=\" ORS=\" original_file > file_you_will_visualize

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\v(\u)\n\s+(\u)/\1\2

\v .............. very magic (avoid a lot of backslashes)
\u .............. uppercase
\n .............. new line
\s+ ............. one space or more
( .............. start of regex group
) .............. end of regex group
```

We are looking for uppercase letters followed by new line, folowed by any number of spaces and finally followed again for uppercase letters. We put togetter only group 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `:g` and family works line-wise, making it difficult to process multiline commands. You could use a regular `:s`:

```
:%s/.*field\s*[^4]: "\_[^"]*"\n
```

This works considering you don't have escaped quotations inside your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If by "agroup" you mean "delete", this might work for you:

```
:%g/field/norm f"d/"/e^Mdd
```

where `^M` is <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

"Find every line that has the text "field", then in this line find a quote, delete till after next quote, then delete the whole line."